# Best method sequence for Ruby on Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In Rails, we offen write a lot of code in our models such as class methods, plugin methods, named_scopes, callbacks... I am wondering if there is a good pattern to organize the sequence. I saw the best example in a presentation before, but now I forgot.

Anyone have suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no set way... If you are using a scope (since Rails 3, named_scope is deprecated) that relies on a method, it has to be defined after the method in the model. It's possible to mix and match and sometimes it's necessary to do so.

It doesn't affect load time or efficiency to the best of my knowledge

Comment: I just want to try to find a best way to organize code...

Comment: It's not about organizing, it's about standardizing. Whatever you do, do it all the time. Then, you have a set of rules to follow for yourself. There is no standard because things change. I prefer to alphabetize when possible because then I can do a human binary search when looking for methods, but I'm a nerd

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty OCD when writing ruby, so I have a very opinionated answer to your question. I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/798042) as an example of the structure we use.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about that a while back as part of my style-guide: 
[acts_as_good_style](http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2007/08/actsasgoodstyle.html).

YMMV as to what the "best" grouping/ordering is, but if you'd like my take it's there under the "Model idiom" section